# Cannot Access property of nested objects vue

Tags: vuejs2, nest-nested-object

I am using Vue for quite sometime now but having troubles on accessing certain property of my object..

I have object named "table" with "data" and "Paginate" properties that is being passed as a Props to my Datatable Vue component. When I try to console.log the "table" object on my Datatable component, I can see that the "data" and "Paginate" properties has values, but when I try to access the using "this.table.data" I get 0 values..

here is the structure of my table object:

```
table : {
     data : array[7],
     paginate: Object
}
```

trying to access the this.table.data on "Mount" of the Vue instance.

Thanks for the help!

Component Code:

```
 <script>
 window.Event = new Vue();

export default {

props: {
        tableid: String,
        settings: Object,
        table: Object,
    },
mounted: function(){
    console.log(this.table);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Need to see some more code. Can you show the whole component?

Comment: @BertEvans edited the question..

Comment: Are you able to demonstrate the issue in a fiddle? I don't see anything really wrong yet.

Comment: let me try @BertEvans. Thanks. But one note though, I can access the property on the updated vue hook.  Do you have any idea if there are problems when we access vue props on mounted hook? thanks.

Comment: That depends on when it is passed from the parent. If it's loaded asynchronously, it won't be there on mounted.

Comment: Another note is I can see the values when I console log only the table object, but when I access the properties of the table object directly like this: 'this.table.data' I cannot access the values, its on my 3rd day debugging this error.

Comment: How is `table` data populated?

Comment: through a request to the database, I am using axios

Answer (score 0):

```js
Vue.component('table-show', {
  template: '#table-show',
  props: {
    table: Object,
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    tables: [{
      data: [1, 2, 3],
      paginate: true
    }, {
      data: [4, 5, 6],
      paginate: true
    }, {
      data: [7, 8, 9],
      paginate: false
    }, ],
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.5/vue.js"></script>
<template id="table-show">
  <li>{{table.data}}</li>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <table-show v-for="table in tables" :table="table"></table-show>
  </ul>
  <pre>
    {{$data.tables}}
  </pre>
</div>
```